# I want to split a big dataframe into multiple dataframes on basis of the rowcount in spark using scala. I am not able to figure it out

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example, 
I have a dataframe with 12000 rows, and I define a threshold of 3000(externally supplied to my code via config), so I would like to split this dataframe into 4 dataframes with 3000 rows each.
If the dataframe has 12500 rows, I will split it into 5 dataframes, 4 with 3000 rows and last one with 500.
**The significance of dataframe here is that if the rowcount of the dataframe is lesser than this, I will not tinker with it.

Comment: Did you achieve your goal about that? If yes can you share?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a close behavior (but not exactly what you specified), you can use the function [randomSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@randomSplit(weights:Array[Double]):Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]]): randomSplit(weights: Array[Double])

The weights are the proportions in each output dataframe. Henve, you cannot specify exactly the number.

In your case (12500 rows), `df.randomSplit(Array(1,1,1,1))` to separate it into 4 approximately equal parts. Or:

```
val n = (df.length / 4).toInt
df.randomSplit((1 to n).map(x => 1).toArray)
```

PS: I think you will cuts of a spark dataframe with "exact number of rows" with Spark

Comment: I have tried your solution, it splits the dataframe,but not deterministic splitting. My data is structured, so I would like to split it schematically. For e.g. I would like to take the first n number of rows, then another n , and so on.